# cpquery function of bnlearn always returns 0 for simple discrete artificial data

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I want to calculate conditional probabilities based on a bayesian network based on some binary data I create. However, using the `bnlearn::cpquery`, always a value of 0 is returned, while `bnlearn::bn.fit` fits a correct model.

```
# Create data for binary chain network X1->Y->X2 with zeros and ones.
# All base rates are 0.5, increase in probability due to parent = .5 (from .25 to.75)
X1<-c(rep(1,9),rep(1,3),1,rep(1,3),rep(0,3),0,rep(0,3),rep(0,9))
Y<-c(rep(1,9),rep(1,3),0,rep(0,3),rep(1,3),1,rep(0,3),rep(0,9))
X2<-c(rep(1,9),rep(0,3),1,rep(0,3),rep(1,3),0,rep(1,3),rep(0,9))
dag1<-data.frame(X1,Y,X2)

# Fit bayes net to data.
res <- hc(dag1)
fittedbn <- bn.fit(res, data = dag1)
# Fitting works as expected, as seen by graph structure and coefficients in fittedbn:
plot(res)
print(fittedbn)

# Conditional probability query
cpquery(fittedbn, event = (Y==1), evidence = (X1==1), method = "ls")
# Using LW method
cpquery(fittedbn, event = (Y==1), evidence = list(X1 = 1), method = "lw")
```

'cpquery' just returns 0. I have also tried using the `predict` function, however this returns an error:

```
predict(object = fittedbn, node = "Y", data = list(X1=="1"), method = "bayes-lw", prob = True)
# Returns:
# Error in check.data(data, allow.levels = TRUE) : 
#  the data must be in a data frame.
```

In the above `cpquery` the expected result is .75, but 0 is returned. This is not specific to this event or evidence, regardless of what event or evidence I put in (e.g `event = (X2==1), evidence = (X1==0)` or `event = (X2==1), evidence = (X1==0 & Y==1)`) the function returns 0.

One thing I tried, as I thought the small amount of observations might be an issue, is to just increase the number of observations (i.e. vertically concatenating the above dataframe with itself a bunch of times), however this did not change the output.

I've seen many threads on `cpquery` and that it can be fragile, but none indicate this issue. To note: the example in 'cpquery' documentation works as expected, so it seems the problem is not due to my environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are fitting a Gaussian Bayes net not a discrete one. If you change your variables to factors before learning `dag1[] <- lapply(dag1, factor)` -- your code will then execute as expected. (re the zero probabilities in the Gaussian net, the probability of a continuous variable exactly equal to a number is always zero, so i dont think you can use this as the event (but is okay as evidence using `lw`)

Comment: Thanks @user20650 ! That solves it. Suggestion on whether I shall delete this question? Can't flag it as solved.